# jQuery.getJSON not returning anything.

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to call a json file, but my function isnt returning anything.

index.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON( 'ebooks.json', function( fb ) {
        alert(fb);
    });          
});
}
```

ebooks.json

```
{
"title" : "software design"
}
```

Comment: If there's no alert at all, the first thing to do is to open your console and look for errors, if there are non, the second thing to do would be to add a fail() handler and see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this, You have added extra `}` in your code,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON( 'ebooks.json', function( fb ) {
            alert(fb);
        });          
    });

</script>
```

You can able to find this errors using in Firefox **Tools->Web Developer ->Error Console** or **CTRL+SHIFT+J**

Comment: NP. Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why to be honest, but it only worked when I declared the ready() function separately and passed this function to $(document).ready.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1 id="titel">Title</h1>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ready() {
        $.getJSON( 'ebooks.json', function( fb ) {
            alert(fb.title);
        });          
    };

    $(document).ready(ready());

</script>
</body>
</html>
```